# Is it ok to reopen a closed question so that it can be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates, reopening

Steven Vascellaro posted the following [comment in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38946725#38946725):

> I'd like to have my question [How early should I arrive for a meeting?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/95462/3192) marked as a duplicate of [What's the best time to arrive for an interview / meeting / appointment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/88660/3192)

What is the guideline to deal with this situation? Is it a good practice to cast reopen votes on a question solely because you want to mark it as a duplicate later?

Comment: I had a look through main meta but can't find anything relevant to this topic. Either it hasn't been asked before or, more likely, it's buried somewhere in the archives because it never got much traction or is awkwardly phrased. Either way, perhaps you could ask the general question on main meta as I'm not aware of a standard procedure on this and it's not site-specific.

Comment: If the question is closed for being "Opinion based" I see no value in opening it up and closing it yet again for being a "Duplicate". Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Lilienthal I found one question on main meta asked a couple of months ago, but it has no answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347897/252576

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 Keep in mind that that's SO meta, not [meta.se].

Comment: @Lilienthal Oh right, I always get confused between the two. :|

Comment: I've started a related discussion on Meta Stack Exchange: *[Why do I need to reopen my question to have it marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298756/351462)*

Answer (score 3):

I'd say take it one step at a time.

We reopen questions if they have been edited to be on topic. Has that happened? Reopen the question.

We close questions as duplicate, if the question is on topic, and has been answered before. Is the question on topic, and has it been answered before? Mark it as duplicate.

I don't think it needs to be forced; if you feel the question as it stands is on-topic for the Workplace, then you can nominate it for reopening. Once that's done, if you feel it's duplicate, mark it as a duplicate. If the community agrees, then what you intended will happen. If the community does not, the process will stall at some point.

But one step at a time.