# What should I do if I found a better duplicate than the currently linked duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

The question [How to deal with boss constantly talking to colleagues, which affect my concentration?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96492/3192) was closed as duplicate of the question [What can I do about a very loud coworker?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4206/3192). However, the OP pointed out in his [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/96492/2) that the situation is different because it involves a boss.

However, there is already another question [Boss plays loud music affecting my concentration. How do I take this up with him?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/91087/3192) which covers that situation, and looks to be a better duplicate than the currently linked one. Of course, when I saw the question in the Reopen queue, I linked the "better" question in a comment.<sup>1</sup> However, linking the question directly as a duplicate would make it more visible and more accessible.

How do we deal with this? Should I flag this post to moderators for a quick fix? Should I cast a reopen vote to (eventually) close it again with the "better" duplicate?

---

<sup>1</sup> Interestingly, before my comment, the OP had commented that he already resolved the issue by following the approach suggested in the accepted answer to the "better" duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either become a [Gold Tag Badge](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) holder or **flag it for moderator attention**. [Both can now edit duplicate links.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

Don't move the question through the reopen process, that's not what it's for. See also [this related question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/is-it-ok-to-reopen-a-closed-question-so-that-it-can-be-marked-as-duplicate/4664#4664) and the [main meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298756/allow-questions-to-be-closed-as-duplicates-without-having-them-reopened-first) it spawned.

Comment: so just to be clear, ANY gold badge would qualify someone for this? SO as an example: user A makes an account today and asks a question that goes viral and they are award the "Great Question" badge. Even though they have only been on the site for one day, they would be able to edit the duplicate?

Comment: @SaggingRufus No, the [tag badge](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) is a distinct badge awarded for contributing on a specific tag. We have a total of 2 unique people who have one. It's similar to the [instant close privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) these badge holders get on questions that were originally asked with that tag.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense